# Changing a class object from another class on a button click

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter to write a basic file browser.  I have a main window that has a list box of files.  When clicking on a button, a search window is opened.  The user enters the search string and it looks to see if it can find it.  This part I have working just fine.  My problem is, I cannot figure out how to get that file/path back to the main window to refresh the list box.

```
class mainWindow(object):
        def __init__(self,master):
                self.master=master
                self.homePath = "/home/scs/python"
                self.fromPath = self.homePath
                self.toPath = self.homePath

                self.lbl=Label(master,text = "Files").grid(row=0,column=0)
                self.lbl1=Label(master, text = "Destination").grid(row=0,column=2)
                self.lblArrow=Label(master,text="-->").grid(row=0, column=1)

                self.lbFrom=Listbox(master)
                self.lbFrom.grid(row=1,column=0)
                self.lbFrom.bind('<Double-Button-1>', lambda evt: self.onDoubleClk(evt, self.fromPath, self.lbFrom, "f"))

                self.lbTo=Listbox(master)
                self.lbTo.grid(row=1,column=2)
                self.lbTo.bind('<Double-Button-1>', lambda evt: self.onDoubleClk(evt,self.toPath, self.lbTo, "t"))


                self.btnSearch=Button(master, text="Search", command=self.searchValue)
                self.btnSearch.grid(row=7,column=1)
                self.btnCp=Button(master, text="Copy", command=self.copyFile)
                self.btnCp.grid(row=5,column=1)
                self.btnMv=Button(master, text="Move", command=self.moveFile)
                self.btnMv.grid(row=6,column=1)


                self.listItems(self.fromPath, self.lbFrom)
                self.listItems(self.toPath, self.lbTo)

def listItems(self, path, box):
                #print "Received path: " + path
                box.delete(0,'end')
                i = 0
                if path != self.homePath:
                        box.insert(i+1, "../")
                        i += 1

                for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
                        #print "Path: "+ str(fromPath)
                        #print "Dirs: " + str(dirs)
                        #print "Files: " + str(files)
                        for d in dirs:
                                box.insert(i+1, "D - " + d)
                                i += 1
                        for f in files:
                                box.insert(i+1, f)
                                i += 1
                        break
def searchValue(self):
                self.w=searchWindow(self.master, self.homePath, self.lbFrom)
                self.master.wait_window(self.w.top)

class searchWindow(object):
        def __init__(self, master, homePath, listBox):
                top=self.top=Toplevel(master)
                x = root.winfo_x()
                y = root.winfo_y()
                self.homePath = homePath
                self.listBox = listBox
                top.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x+100, y+100))
                self.l=Label(top,text="File Search")
                self.l.grid(row=0,column=1)
                self.e=Entry(top)
                self.e.grid(row=0,column=2, columnspan=2)
                self.ok=Button(top,text="Ok", command=self.searchOk)
                self.ok.grid(row=1,column=1)
                self.cancel=Button(top, text="Cancel", command = self.cancel)
                self.cancel.grid(row=1,column=2)
                homePath = "Blah"

        def searchOk(self):
                self.searchValue=self.e.get()
                found=False
                print "serach term: " + self.searchValue
                for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(self.homePath, topdown=True):
                        for f in files:
                                if self.searchValue == f:

                                        print "Found it"
                                        print os.path.abspath(f)
                                        found=True
                                        break
                                else:
                                        print "didn't find it"
                        if found:
                                break
                if not found:
                        self.popup()

                self.top.destroy()

        def cancel(self):
                self.top.destroy()

        def popup(self):
                p=Tk()
                l = Label(p, text="Search not found")
                b = Button(p, text="ok", command=p.destroy)
                l.pack()
                b.pack()
                p.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just before you destroy the search window, call a method in the main window with the new info: `self.master.search_result(found)`. Since you didn't subclass Toplevel (as you should) you will need to add `self.master = master` to the `__init__` method for this to work.

Comment: You may also like to know that `tkinter.messagebox.showwarning` exists, so you don't have to write the `popup()` code yourself.